# How to fix error expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize, data-preprocessing

I tried to do text preprocessing with several steps. the last step for text preprocessing that I did was normalization and tokenization.

the code i use is as follows:

```
#--------Normalizing-------
normalizad_word = pd.read_excel("/content/colloquial.xlsx")

normalizad_word_dict = {}

for index, row in normalizad_word.iterrows():
    if row[0] not in normalizad_word_dict:
        normalizad_word_dict[row[0]] = row[1] 

def normalized_term(document):
    result = []
    for term in document:
        if term in normalizad_word_dict:
            for word in normalizad_word_dict[term].split(' '):
                result.append(word)
        else:
            result.append(term)
    return result

dataset['review_normalized'] = dataset['single_char'].apply(normalized_term)

# NLTK word tokenize 
def word_tokenize_wrapper(text):
    return word_tokenize(text)

dataset['review_tokens'] = dataset['review_normalized'].apply(word_tokenize_wrapper)
```

But getting error like this:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-fe7f23995409> in <module>
     67     return word_tokenize(text)
     68 
---> 69 dataset['review_tokens'] = dataset['review_normalized'].apply(word_tokenize_wrapper)
     70 
     71 print('Result : \n')

14 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py in _match_potential_end_contexts(self, text)
   1373         before_words = {}
   1374         matches = []
-> 1375         for match in reversed(list(self._lang_vars.period_context_re().finditer(text))):
   1376             # Ignore matches that have already been captured by matches to the right of this match
   1377             if matches and match.end() > before_start:

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

does anyone know how to solve it? thank you so much.

Comment: Its worth checking if the value contains NaN (None/null) in dataset['review_normalized'] column. If yes, replace all NaN with empty string ''.

Comment: I searched in this community for how to replace NaN with empty string. I try:
`dataset['review_normalized'] = dataset['review_normalized'].fillna('')` and `dataset['review_normalized'] = dataset['review_normalized'].replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)` but still error

Comment: Can you try converting all values to string ?

from:
word_tokenize(text)

to:
word_tokenize(str(text))

or 
dataset[['review_normalized']] = dataset[['review_normalized']].astype(str)